# Still giving me a repeating vector

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ programmer, I would like to ask you a simple question but I do not understand why output still give me repeating data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int nfft;

    nfft = 256;
    vector<float>f;

    for(unsigned i=0; i<nfft; i++){
        f.push_back(((i/(nfft-1))-0.5)*8e6);

    }

    for(unsigned i=0;i<nfft;i++){
        cout << f[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

My expectation is a vector: [-4.0000   -3.9686   -3.9373   -3.9059   -3.8745   -3.8431   -3.8118   -3.7804   -3.7490   -3.7176   -3.6863   -3.6549 .......  3.9059    3.9373    3.9686    4.0000]

Please give me a hand to solve this problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: integer division gives you zero all the time... cast `i` as float in your push_back call.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeating data"?

Comment: @AndyG the output of this program is -4e+06 repeated a number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(i/(nfft-1))` is well protected with parentheses and thus performs an *integer division*.

Since `nfft > i` you get zero => always the same value.

Example of how to ix:

```
f.push_back(((float(i)/(nfft-1))-0.5)*8e6)
```